# Can I access a property from my manifest.json in my extension's JavaScript files?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'd like to refer to the version number as defined in my `manifest.json` in my extension's JavaScript files.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Since chrome 22 you should use `chrome.runtime.getManifest()`. [See docs here.](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html#method-getManifest)

So now it is as simple as:

```
var manifest = chrome.runtime.getManifest();
console.log(manifest.name);
console.log(manifest.version);
```

Comment: +1 , make sure to test if its available first.  if(typeof ( chrome.runtime.getManifest ) == 'function'){

Comment: Because of Chrome automatic update feature that can't be disabled by an ordinary user I suppose currently nobody uses version below 22. But it is a good idea to include to the manifest: **"minimum_chrome_version" : "22.0.0.0"**

Answer (score 4):

I think that this is what you're looking for http://www.martinsikora.com/accessing-manifest-json-in-a-google-chrome-extension

```
chrome.manifest = (function() {
    var manifestObject = false;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            manifestObject = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        }
    };
    xhr.open("GET", chrome.extension.getURL('/manifest.json'), false);

    try {
        xhr.send();
    } catch(e) {
        console.log('Couldn\'t load manifest.json');
    }

    return manifestObject;

})();
```

And that's all. This short code snippet loads manifest object and put's it among other `chrome.*` APIs. So, now you can get any information you want:

```
// current version
chrome.manifest.version

// default locale
chrome.manifest.default_locale
```

Comment: Perfect, this worked.  The only thing I had to change was the name of the IIFE to manifest instead of chrome.manifest.